# Time schedule intersection

Tags: c#, interview-questions, interval

I had a job interview one of the questions was the following
Given an api - you submit a name of a person and it gives back a sorted list of all the free time slots this person has. the list might be very long.

```
List<TimePeriod> GetTimesAvail(String person)
```

You are given list of people and I need to implement a function which give you back a list of time periods where all the people are available at the same time.

example for simplicity all the free time slots are on the same date

- 23/3/2017 - 00:59-1:30,  2:00-2:30, 3:00-3:30 //personA
- 23/3/2017 - 1:00 -1:45, 3:00 -4:00 //personB
- 23/3/2017 1:00am - 5:00pm //personC

result - 1:00-1:30 , 3:00 -3:30

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace JobInterviewTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class Question
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            List<string> people = new List<string> { "personA", "personB", "personC" };
            List<TimePeriod> result = GetTimeSlotForAll(people);
            Assert.AreEqual(1,result[0].Start.Hour);
            Assert.AreEqual(0,result[0].Start.Minute);
            Assert.AreEqual(1,result[0].End.Hour);
            Assert.AreEqual(30,result[0].End.Minute);

            Assert.AreEqual(3, result[1].Start.Hour);
            Assert.AreEqual(0, result[1].Start.Minute);
            Assert.AreEqual(3, result[1].End.Hour);
            Assert.AreEqual(30, result[1].End.Minute);
        }

        private List<TimePeriod> GetTimeSlotForAll(List<string> people)
        {
            if (people == null || people.Count == 0)
            {
                return new List<TimePeriod>();
            }
            //future improvment -- suggested
            //List<List<TimePeriod>> tempTimeList = new List<List<TimePeriod>>();
            //foreach (var person in people)
            //{
            //    var personList = Utiliies.GetTimesAvail(person);
            //    tempTimeList.Add(personList);
            //}
            //List<Dictionary<string, List<TimePeriod>>> dictionaryList = new List<Dictionary<string, List<TimePeriod>>>();
            //foreach (var list in tempTimeList)
            //{
            //    //key is the day/month/year
            //    Dictionary<string, List<TimePeriod>> personDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<TimePeriod>>();
            //    foreach (var time in list)
            //    {
            //        if (personDictionary.ContainsKey(time.ToDateTimeDay()))
            //        {
            //            personDictionary[time.ToDateTimeDay()].Add(time);
            //        }
            //        else
            //        {
            //            personDictionary[time.ToDateTimeDay()] = new List<TimePeriod>();
            //            personDictionary[time.ToDateTimeDay()].Add(time);
            //        }
            //    }
            //    dictionaryList.Add(personDictionary);
            //}

            //place the first person meetings a the first result
            List<TimePeriod> firstPersonList = Utiliies.GetTimesAvail(people.FirstOrDefault());
            List<TimePeriod> result = new List<TimePeriod>();
            //intersect the meetings with the others
            for (int i = 1; i < people.Count; i++)
            {
                List<TimePeriod> secondPersonList = Utiliies.GetTimesAvail(people[i]);
                foreach (var secondSlot in secondPersonList)
                {
                    foreach (var firstSlot in firstPersonList)
                    {
                        if (secondSlot.SameDay(firstSlot))
                        {
                            CheckHourIntersections(firstSlot, secondSlot, result);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //copy the result into the first person
                firstPersonList.Clear();
                foreach (var timeSlot in result)
                {
                    firstPersonList.Add(new TimePeriod(timeSlot.Start, timeSlot.End));
                }
                //clear result
                result.Clear();
            }
            return firstPersonList;
        }

        private static void CheckHourIntersections(TimePeriod firstSlot, TimePeriod secondSlot, List<TimePeriod> result)
        {
            // check all the different interval intersections
            //one intersects with the start of anothesr
            //[-----] //firstSlot
            //  [------] //secondSlot
            // 00:59 -> 1:30 --- 01:00 -> 01:45
            //also cover 
            //[-----] //firstSlot
            //[------] //secondSlot
            //also cover
            //[-------] //firstSlot
            // [------] //secondSlot
            if (((firstSlot.Start.Hour < secondSlot.Start.Hour) || (firstSlot.Start.Hour == secondSlot.Start.Hour && firstSlot.Start.Minute > secondSlot.Start.Minute)) 
                && ((firstSlot.End.Hour < secondSlot.End.Hour) ||(firstSlot.End.Hour == secondSlot.End.Hour && firstSlot.End.Minute < secondSlot.End.Minute))
                && ((secondSlot.Start.Hour < firstSlot.End.Hour) || (firstSlot.End.Hour == secondSlot.End.Hour && firstSlot.End.Minute < secondSlot.End.Minute)) )
            {
                result.Add(new TimePeriod(secondSlot.Start, firstSlot.End));
                return;
            }
            // [----] //firstSlot //02:00 -> 02:30
            //[------] //secondSlot 01:00->01:45
            if (((firstSlot.Start.Hour > secondSlot.Start.Hour) ||(firstSlot.Start.Hour == secondSlot.Start.Hour && firstSlot.Start.Minute >= secondSlot.Start.Minute))
                && ((firstSlot.End.Hour < secondSlot.End.Hour)|| (firstSlot.End.Hour == secondSlot.End.Hour && firstSlot.End.Minute < secondSlot.End.Minute)))
            {
                result.Add(new TimePeriod(firstSlot.Start, firstSlot.End));
                return;
            }
            //    [----] //firstSlot
            //[------] //secondSlot
            if (((firstSlot.Start.Hour > secondSlot.Start.Hour && firstSlot.Start.Minute < secondSlot.Start.Minute) || (firstSlot.Start.Hour == secondSlot.Start.Hour && firstSlot.Start.Minute > secondSlot.Start.Minute))
                && ((firstSlot.End.Hour > secondSlot.End.Hour && firstSlot.End.Minute < secondSlot.End.Minute) || (firstSlot.End.Hour == secondSlot.End.Hour && firstSlot.End.Minute > secondSlot.End.Minute)))
            {
                result.Add(new TimePeriod(firstSlot.Start, secondSlot.End));
            }
        }
    }
    [DebuggerDisplay("{Start.Hour}:{Start.Minute}->{End.Hour}:{End.Minute}")]
    public class TimePeriod
    {
        public DateTime Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime End { get; set; }

        public TimePeriod(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            Start = start;
            End = end;
        }

        public bool SameDay(TimePeriod other)
        {
            return this.Start.Year == other.Start.Year && this.Start.Month == other.Start.Month &&
            this.Start.Day == other.Start.Day;
        }
        public string ToDateTimeDay()
        {
            return Start.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }

    public static class Utiliies
    {
        public static List<TimePeriod> GetTimesAvail(String person)
        {
            var res = new List<TimePeriod>();
            if (person == "personA")
            {
                res.Add(new TimePeriod(new DateTime(2017, 3, 23, 0, 59, 00), new DateTime(2017, 3, 23, 1, 30, 00)));
                res.Add(new TimePeriod(new DateTime(2017, 3, 23, 2, 00, 00), new DateTime(2017, 3, 23, 2, 30, 00)));
                res.Add(new TimePeriod(new DateTime(2017, 3, 23, 3, 00, 00), new DateTime(2017, 3, 23, 3, 30, 00)));
            }
            if (person == "personB")
            {
                res.Add(new TimePeriod(new DateTime(2017, 3, 23, 1, 00, 00), new DateTime(2017, 3, 23, 1, 45, 00)));
                res.Add(new TimePeriod(new DateTime(2017, 3, 23, 3, 00, 00), new DateTime(2017, 3, 23, 4, 00, 00)));
            }
            if (person == "personC")
            {
                res.Add(new TimePeriod(new DateTime(2017, 3, 23, 00, 00, 00), new DateTime(2017, 3, 23, 14, 00, 00)));
            }
            return res;
        }
    }


}
```

I had about 20 mins to write the code and talk about complexity.
one suggestion I made since the list of free TimePeriod could be very long is to store a 
 `List<Dictionary<day+month, TimePeriod>> persons`

so we would only call the API in the beginning for the list of all of the names and than later on use a dictionary to fetch the TimePeriods for a certain date.

something like this:

```
List<List<TimePeriod>> temptimeList = new  List<List<TimePeriod>>();
    foreach(var person in people)
    {
        var personList = getTimesAvail(person);
        tempTimelist.Add(personList);
    }

    List<Dictionary<DateTime, TimePeriod>> dictionaryList = new   List<Dictionary<DateTime, TimePeriod>>();
    foreach(var list in temptimeList)
    {
        Dictionary <DateTime, TimePeriod> personDictionary = new <DateTime, TimePeriod>();
        foreach(var time in list)
        {
            personDictionary.Add(time.ToDateTimeDay(), time);
        }
    }
```

My question is:
Can you please point out where is my code not optimal? I am talking about algorithm and time complexity. please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: The nesting went here out of control :-) When I see somthing like this the time complexity doesn't matter. You wouldn't get the job ;-( This can (should) be refactored into multiple methods.

Comment: `if (...)` code not yet written is off-topic I'm afraid.

Comment: @t3chb0t hey man thanks, I wouldn't put this code anywhere, just remember, I was writing on notepad++ in 20 mins a rough idea.

Comment: @t3chb0t why off-topic? must I really implement the endless code if the checking for an intersection just to get an answer about code complexity?

Comment: _Can you please point out where is my code not optimal?_ - How can anyone point the suboptimal code if many parts are misssing?

Comment: Why don't you complete it and write the missing parts and then post the working version? I'd be glad to review it.

Comment: @t3chb0t I wasn't asked to write that code, just to explain in high level how does the intersection check works.

Comment: Well, this is **Code** Review, without code there is no review. Let's see what the others think but I guess it'll get closed.

Comment: @t3chb0t nevermind i'll remove the question I appreciate the help

Comment: @t3chb0t I have completed the code and now it is working. thanks

Comment: Good job improving it but I'm afraid it'll still get closed for this part _//future improvment -- suggested_ because it's still not yet written code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Review

- `GetTimeSlotForAll` does 2 distinct things: (1) it loads time slots by people (2) it slices time slots to get shared free time. Each of these operations should have its own method. ([single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle))
- `GetTimeSlotForAll` should return `IEnumerable<TimePeriod>` rather than `List<TimePeriod>` because it's intended to enumerate upon, not to change its content.
- `Utiliies` is missing his second `t`.

---

#### Reduce complexity

`CheckHourIntersections` is way too complex. An interval intersection with an included end date takes the max start and min end date, provided the start is smaller than or equal to the end.

> ```
> private static void CheckHourIntersections(
>     TimePeriod firstSlot, TimePeriod secondSlot, List<TimePeriod> result)
> {
>     if (/*edge case: overlap ..*/)
>     {
>         result.Add(new TimePeriod(secondSlot.Start, firstSlot.End));
>         return; 
>     }
>     if (/*edge case: contains ..*/)
>     {
>         result.Add(new TimePeriod(firstSlot.Start, firstSlot.End));
>         return; 
>     }
>     if (/*edge case: contained by ..*/)
>     {
>         result.Add(new TimePeriod(firstSlot.Start, secondSlot.End));
>         return; 
>     }
> }
> ```

simplified:

```
private static void CheckHourIntersections(
    TimePeriod source, TimePeriod target, List<TimePeriod> result)
{
    // check all the different interval intersections
    var start = source.Start >= target.Start ? source.Start : target.Start;
    var end = source.End <= target.End ? source.End : target.End;

    if (end >= start)
    {
        result.Add(new TimePeriod(start, end));
    }
}
```

`SameDay` is too complex. `DateTime.Date` gives a `DateTime` instance that represents the start of that day corresponding to the specified instance.

> ```
> public bool SameDay(TimePeriod other)
> {
>     return this.Start.Year == other.Start.Year 
>         && this.Start.Month == other.Start.Month &&
>     this.Start.Day == other.Start.Day;
> }
> ```

simplified:

```
public bool SameDay(TimePeriod other)
{
    return Start.Date == other.Start.Date;
}
```